# How to seperate a number into smaller components? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

I am making a JavaScript app that calculates the result of two numbers multiplied. How do I show the components of a number? For example, number = 123. hundreds = 1, tens = 2, ones = 3.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you expect the output for this number `1200356`  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop in which it checks until the number becomes zero. You can take the mod with 10 of the number and divide it by 10.

Comment: could you show me your answer with code using the example of 123?